# How does magic find work in Path of Exile?

Tags: path-of-exile

As per question title, how does it work? What are the differences of being in a party or playing alone? Does it apply to finding orbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic Find is calculated using the Increased Item Quantity(IIQ) and Increased Item Rarity(IIR) of the player that gets credit for the kill. If a minion gets the kill, then any IIQ/IIR from support gems affecting that minion are applied first.

From my experience this also affects opening chest, so when we go out in a party, we usually have the person with the highest MF open the chests.

I think IIQ is the only stat that will give you more orbs, while IIR increases the rarity (color) of an item.

**Edit** Thanks to Kexlox for finding this information on IIQ in parties:

> When in a party, each player in the party after the first gives a +50% item quantity modifier on drops.

Source: [Mechanics Thread](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/11707/)

Comment: IIQ/IIR ?  What's that ?

Comment: Increased Item Quantity and Increased Item Rarity. I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: Partying also provides a +50% boost to IIQ per player.  So a party of 3 will find twice as many items as a solo player.

Comment: @Kexlox I was not aware of that. Would you like to submit that as an answer, or do you mind if I incorporate it into mine?

Comment: go ahead, the info comes from http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/11707/ which is a pretty good primer on most of the nuts and bolts of the system

Comment: IIQ and IIR in general *do not* apply to chests. [source](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/11707/page/196#p2722419)